# Increment computed property and bind to element in each iteration

Tags: ember.js

My goal is want to give id for select element which is iteratively inside of 
`{{each}}` helper.

For example, first select should have id UDF_CHAR_1, second have UDF_CHAR_2, 
and goes on.

I am binding computed attribute to id property of select. 
In the computed attribute i am increasing counter. The problem is instead of 
assigning id iteratively, it assigns UDF_CHAR1 to all.

My guess is the computed attribute gets calculated once. It is not invoked each 
time inside of `{{each}}`.

Check it here : http://jsbin.com/OvUNaCOK/2/edit

Any solution to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you use the model's property ?: <select name="test" {{bind-attr id=item.idTest}} multiple>

Comment: OP, you are right. The computed property is only called one time, even in a loop. From the docs: `The fullName function will be called once (regardless of how many times it is accessed) as long as it's dependencies have not been changed. Once firstName or lastName are updated any future calls (or anything bound) to fullName will incorporate the new values.` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html

Comment: @fanta: Yes i can. But its not my requirement. My question is how to assign id to the element iteratively inside loop?

Comment: Why do you need to generate the IDs like this? Usually you won't ever need to refer to the actual DOM element by ID when using Ember...

Comment: I agree... I'm having trouble seeing why this is necessary.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte: I posted the reason why i need this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300703/how-to-differentiate-element-and-handle-events-in-ember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new collection from the content of the ArrayController, that calculates the id for each item:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  contentWithIds:function(){
    var content = this.get('content') || [];
    return content.map(function(item, index) {
      item.id = "UDF_CHAR" + (index + 1);
      return item;
    });
  }.property('content.[]'),
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsbin.com/EkitOgi/1/edit

Comment: I have done the same as you said. I have another requirement i.e, In the actions i want to change model data say item.id. How can i access that property in the actions?

Comment: @Susai You can pass parameters in the action helper: `{{action "someMethod" param1 param2}}`. So I guess in your case it would be `{{action "testClick" item.id}}`.

Comment: I have tried the same. Please check it and guide me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330951/couldnt-access-and-modify-model-data-inside-controller

Answer (score 2):

I think most likely you do NOT want to be referencing the `select` elements using the `id`, and there is a much better way to accomplish what you are trying to do. If you update your question with what you are trying to accomplish or ask a new question maybe we can help solve the problem in a more "ember" way that fits better with the framework.

However, if you really want to do it you can use a computed property on the controller to update each item with the desired `id` for each `select` item:

```
annotatedItems: function() {
  return this.get('model').map(function(item, index, enumerable){
    item.id = "UDF_CHAR" + index;
    return item;
  });
}.property('model'),
```

This uses the [`Array.map` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_map) to add an `id` field to each of the elements in your `model` array. You would then loop over this `annotatedItems` computed property using an `{{#each}}` helper, and the `id` element will be accessible as `item.id` in this example:

```
{{#each item in annotatedItems}}
  <select name="test" {{bind-attr id=item.id}} multiple>
    <option>{{item.title}}</option>
    <option>{{item.alias}}</option>     
  </select>
  <button name="button" {{action 'testClick'}}>Click</button>
{{/each}}
```

[updated JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/OvUNaCOK/9/edit)

Comment: Your answer fulfils my question.Thanks. Sorry, i agree my question is not to the point. I posted new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300703/how-to-differentiate-element-and-handle-events-in-ember

Comment: I have done the same as you said. I have another requirement i.e, In the actions i want to change model data say item.id. How can i access that property in the actions?