# Couldn't access and modify model data inside Controller

Tags: ember.js

I have tried example program using Ember as in http://jsbin.com/IyeNucoj/3/edit

I need to access and modify some model properties like isSingleLine, isMultiLine, 
    isPickList in controller actions.

It throws exception like #Object doesn't has set method. I couldn't figure out the 
    problem.

For example,

In Template :

```
<input type="radio" {{bind-attr checked=item.isSingleLine}} 
   {{action 'changeBlk1' item}}>
```

In Controller :

```
actions:{
   changeBlk1:function(item){

//The following thing is not working. throws exception
       item.set('isSingleLine',true);
       item.set('isMultiLine',false);
       item.set('isPickList',false);
   },
   changeBlk2:function(item){

   },
   changeBlk3:function(item){

  }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. That makes it easier to find the problem on jsbin.

Comment: @claptimes: Question is updated.

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `set` because it appears your items are all JavaScript objects instead of being Ember Models. You can follow the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976333/how-to-change-value-with-ember-js-array-foreach) stack overflow and use:

```
Ember.set(item, 'isSingleLine', true);
```